# Finding equal or similar sequences in a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to transform a list into an empty one if it has two non-overlapping sequences with a certain property. E.g. in this case, equals and with length >= 2)

```
mm[{___, b1__, ___, b1__, ___}] := {} /; Length[{b1}] >= 2
```

or, for example 2 sublists, with a similarity function equal 0 and
Legth = 4

```
mm[{___, b1__, ___, b2__, ___}] := {} /;
NeedlemanWunschSimilarity[{b1}, {b2}] == 0 && Length[{b1}] == 4 &&
Length[{b2}] == 4
```

and so on.....

For mathematica, guru who know internal algorithm, is there a faster
way, perhaps using PatternTest (?) ?

Comment: What are the elements in your lists?  Can you provide sample lists?  What is the maximum sequence length you need to work with?

Comment: I always test a list of binary, say, {0,1,0,1,.......,0}, and i need to test False or True if 2 non overlapping parts (not always with same lenght) are a simple transformation of the other. I mean "transformations" like, equality (no trasformation), rotations,inversion, etc... Or there is a faster way to do it?

Comment: To really get an efficient solution, you need to provide a function that would bring your sequences to some canonical form, for each transformation you are interested in. Otherwise, any solution is bound to perform pairwise comparisons, which means it will be `O(n^2)` if `n` is a length of the list. One may be able to optimize the constant factor in front of `n^2` (perhaps very considerably in some cases), using some tricks, but for really large lists that won't help much.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin . Can you explain better what You mean for example for string rotation?

Comment: For string rotation that would be probably sorting string characters. In general, this is a function which, when applied to different expressions (sequences here) which we want to consider equal, will transform all of them to the same expression. This would allow to efficiently group sequences according to their equivalence classes. To have such a function is a stronger requirement than to have a comparison function.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin So if i well undestood,in previous example if you chek rotation equivalence class, You say instead of changing second part of expression with `/;RotateLeft[{b1},Length[{b1}]==Length[{b2}]` to implement which code? Be patient with me!

Comment: No. I meant that there is such `f`, that `f[{b1}] == f[{b2}]`, where `f` is a function which brings `{b1}` and `{b2}` to canonical form. Whenever such `f` exists and you know it, you can hope for a more efficient solution. Typically, `f` should bring its argument to an equivalent but "canonical" form, which will be the same for all equivalent elements. `Length` is not such a function in your case. For rotated list, `Sort` is one possibility, but it may be too general.

Answer (score 4):

I await a fuller description of what you are doing, but in the mean time:

```
mm2[{___, b1 : Repeated[_, {4}], ___, b2 : Repeated[_, {4}], ___}] := {} /; 
  NeedlemanWunschSimilarity[{b1}, {b2}] == 0
```

This uses [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html) to test only sequences of the correct length.

You can specify a minimum and maximum sequence length with `Repeated[_, {min, max}]`.

Comment: My task is to mark a list when two non overlapping subsequences are one the transform of the other i.e. basically are equal, one is a rotation of the other, is reverse of the other and so on. In my opinion the ___ notation is very computative expensive, but Mathematica has implemented a lot of similarity function! So I imagine every shortcut possible

Comment: @user By the way, welcome to StackOverflow.  Have you tested the form with `Repeated` that I show above?  Also, it is hard to optimize a solution without more knowledge of the data.  If you want a very general and flexible solution, it may be hard to beat the form I show above.  Are the sequences always the same length?  Are all the elements in your list of the same type (float, integer, etc.)?

Comment: @user1063646 Without knowing anything about the precise comparison test, the only solution I see is testing all possibilities (selecting all sub-sequences and comparing them).  This is what Mathematica makes very easy using pattern matches.  But obviously it's slow.  **Also:**  Please add the calrifications in the original question, so everyone can easily see them.

Comment: @Szabolcs it still can be much faster than his initial pattern.  I do hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: thanx for welcome. the sequences not always are of the same length, but often are with minimal length n; In every case are applied on integers (i.e a binary list , es {0,1,1,.....,0}